# Why do the water pipes around my water meter vibrate when water is flowing?

Tags: plumbing, water

I have a problem where there is a vibration in the cold water pipes whenever water is flowing (i.e. a tap is running, just after the toilet has been flushed etc.). The vibration appears to be focused around the water meter, although it's not clear if it is the water meter causing the vibrations or the pipes. As a rough guess the vibration is around the 2-4Hz range, and is fairly constant whilst water is flowing, gradually getting quieter once the water has stopped flowing. It also doesn't start when there are either small or constant low flows. Can anyone tell me what might be causing the vibrations and if this is something that could be fixed myself (i.e. turn the water off and on again) or if this is something that I will need a plumber to look at?

Answer (score 7):

Hearing a small amount of noise from a water meter vibrating is not uncommon, however if the noise is loud enough to be distracting, you may have a worn impeller in the meter. You can try holding the meter securely or applying some pressure to the meter to see it that reduces the noise, but also you will be able to feel if the vibration is coming from the meter itself.  If simply holding the meter or the lines attached reduce the noise to an acceptable level, then securing the pipes to a wall bracket or clamping them securely may be all you need to do.  If this test does not lower the noise and you can feel the vibration through the meter housing, then I'd suggest calling your water utility company.  They own the meter and would come out to replace it if necessary, usually at no cost to the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

It could be air in the pipe system. A plumber should be able to fix this quite easily, and would be worth doing as this sort of problem could really get on your nerves!

Answer (score 0):

I want to add something here: i had a similar issue HOWEVER, I changed the PRV and it did nothing. The past four months I have been working with the city I live in, and we finally discovered it...it was an issue in another house propagating to several other houses in the neighborhood. I read many threads about humming in pipes in a house and never saw it mentioned that it might be coming from another house. I'm glad to have the problem solved.